# Search element from an array through manual index

Tags: php, arrays

is it possible to find an element in an array after some specific index in php, Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide any code attempt you've made? And maybe clarify the question a little better?

Comment: Try to be more specific when asking the question.

Comment: i am sorry for any problem,i am new to the stack overflow, i will improve it as soon as possible.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather vague, so the answer will depend on how your data is structured. If you have a plain, indexed array with sequential keys, you can search a slice of your array:

```
function array_search_from($needle, $haystack, $index_from)
{
    $array_to_search = array_slice($haystack, $index_from);

    $index = array_search($needle, $array_to_search);

    if ($index === false)
    {
        return $index;
    }

    return $index + $index_from;
}
```

.. or you can implement it as a regular for loop to avoid creating the slice:

```
function array_search_from($needle, $haystack, $index_from)
{
    $len = count($haystack);

    for ($i = $index_from; $i < $len; $i++)
    {
        if ($haystack[$i] == $needle)
        {
            return $i;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

To test that it works as expected:

```
$array = array("one", "two", "three", "four", "one", "two");

var_dump(array_search_from("one", $array, 0));
var_dump(array_search_from("one", $array, 1));
var_dump(array_search_from("two", $array, 2));   

int(0)
int(4)
int(5)
```

You can then expand this into array_search_slice, and probably add a bit better error checking (such as array_search returning NULL if invalid arguments are provided).

For fun, since PHP associative arrays also are sequences, you can also do the same with associative arrays:

```
function array_search_from($needle, $haystack, $from)
{
    $searching = false;

    foreach ($haystack as $key => $value)
    {
        if ($key == $from)
        {
            $searching = true;
        }

        if ($searching && ($needle == $value))
        {
            return $key;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

.. and testing them:

```
$array = array("one" => "foo", "two" => "bar", "three" => "baz", "four" => "woo", "five" => "foo", "six" => "bar");

var_dump(array_search_from("foo", $array, "one"));
var_dump(array_search_from("foo", $array, "two"));
var_dump(array_search_from("bar", $array, "three"));
```

.. results in:

```
string(3) "one"
string(4) "five"
string(3) "six"
```

.. which might not be that useful, but can be done. And therefore, it has been done.

Comment: fiskfisk you are life saver, it was awesome to deal with your code!